# I can't get form element using $refs

Tags: vuejs2

I can't get the form element. I tried to show this.$refs, but this.$refs is empty object({}). what's wrong?

```
<template>
    <view>
    // some view
    </view>
    <view>
         <form ref="myForm" v-on:submit:prevent="getFormId" report-submit>
         </form>
    </view>
</template>
<script>
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.$refs);
        console.log(this.$refs.myForm);
    }
</script>
```

The result is follows.
{}
undefined

Comment: You can just v-model for two way binding of form elements. Why do you need get the form ?

Comment: Your template has two root `<view>` elements. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element

Comment: i'm trying to get the form element and trigger the submit event and get the formId of the form(report-submit is used to get the formId)

Answer (score 1):

You can only access direct children of a component. If the ref you are trying to access is inside another component, it will not work. You would have to access the ref on the `<View>` component.

Comment: Could you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes I've noticed issues with using hyphen and case sensitive refs. what happens if you refer to it as `this.$refs['myForm']` and if that returns an array add `[0]` onto the end. or just change the ref to `form`. but if you are trying to get all the values inside of the form this is incorrect.

```
<template>
    <form @submit:prevent="submit">
        <input type="text" v-model="name" required autofocus>
        <input type="email" v-model="email" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>
<script>
exports default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: '',
            email: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            console.log({name: this.name, email: this.email });
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, i can't get it. the code you show has no refs. i'm trying to get the form element and trigger the submit event and get the formId of the form(report-submit is used to get the formId)